# Version numbers in database?

Tags: mysql

What is a version number in database and suppose if there are multiple tables and in each tables records are getting modified so is it necessary to have version number. Under what circumstances we should use version numbers in database?

Comment: you mean Mysql version?

Comment: Yes MySql Version and i am very confused why to have version numbers in database.

Answer (score 0):

you want to find out MySql version by using below SQL.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

Thank you.

Comment: Suppose  i have a registration table with name,id ,department,contact_no ,location  and when a user wants to modify his profile ,let say he modifyied location and contact_no with same id.So the id will be same but suppose record has been modified has for five times .So in this scenario how can we use version_number for the table when record is getting modified.?

Comment: In that scenario, You can add one more column call last_update. Every time user has modified data at same time you can update that last_update. You can easily find out latest modified id.